# Tensorflow: how to make sure all samples in each batch are with different labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wonder whether there is a way to apply constraints on the batches to generate in Tensorflow. In particular, I would like to produce batches containing different labels.

Suppose I have five possible labels, `{A, B, C, D, E}`, I would like batches like `(A, C, E, D, B)` or `(B,E,D,C,A)`. Basically, I want to avoid batches with equal labels such as `(A, A, D, E, C)` or `(A, B, B, B, E)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Implementing what you asked

Batching simply extracts `BATCH_SIZE` samples from whatever it gets as input and packs them together, so technically yes, that's possible. It's up to you, however, making sure that the input to `batch()` is sorted the way you want.

Probably the most efficient way to do this would be to have 5 `tf.data.Dataset`s, each with a specific label, `zip` them together to obtain one "batched" dataset with labels always in the same order, then `.map` on it [`tf.random_shuffle`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_shuffle) to obtain a random permutation of the batch and feed this to your network.

I'd also throw in a `.shuffle` after the random permutation, just t make sure that the network doesn't see the same batch always in the same order.

In code that would look something like:

```
data = [ tf.constant([chr(ord('A')+i), chr(ord('a')+i) ]) for i in range(5) ]

per_label_datasets = [tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(d) for d in data]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip(tuple(per_label_datasets)) # now an item has shape len(per_label_datasets) and one item from each
dataset = dataset.map(lambda *args : tf.random_shuffle(args)) # lambda needed because random_shuffle takes only one argument
dataset = dataset.shuffle(10) # optional

it = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
batch = it.get_next()

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(batch))
print(sess.run(batch))
```

sample output:

```
[b'a' b'c' b'd' b'e' b'b']
[b'C' b'B' b'A' b'D' b'E']
```

### Personal note

I don't know what model you're using, and I assume out there there are models for which this would make sense, but **in most models the order of samples in the batch is meaningless because results are averaged together over a batch when calculating the loss**. So, if you really need this, there are ways to do it, but make sure you actually need it before starting to code the pipeline.

Comment: I agree with your personal note, indeed I need to tweak my batch generator because I'm implementing a triplet loss function where I want to compare different examples and similar examples.